# Process script for 3 forms on one page useing the GET method

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I need a processing script for my home page contact section that has 3 different named forms (CONTACT,ORDER,QUOTE) but all three have the exact same layout like this (NAME,EMAIL,COMMENT,SEND).
I am using the GET method on my contact forms because it sends info to a function.php the calls the processing script.
So I need the script to send only the form that was filled to my email address. Right now when I fill a form and click send I get 3 emails from all 3 named forms. Here is the address of the form page."http://www.viperay.com/contact"

Comment: Whats your question? Sounds like you're just looking for code which this site isn't for.

Comment: No I'm not just looking for code. I already have it wrote. I just need to know what I am missing or a better way to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your 3 forms are not nested and you have a submit button in each form, then the only data that will be sent to the server is the submitted form data, not the data from other forms on the page.

Also, I recommend you to use a POST for your form. That should not change anything but it's best practice

Comment: Thanks Adrien for the feedback. Im not sure what you mean by nested but as for the way I have them now is in my contact script I have all 3 wrote inline like this "

Comment: Thanks Adrien for the feedback. Im not sure what you mean by nested but as for the way I have them now is in my contact script I have all 3 wrote inline. If you go to my link and look at the code you can see how I did this."http://www.viperay.com/contact" It starts on line 141. The submit button calls my function.php and that calls the process script. Only it send ALL 3 forms to my mail box other than the form that was filled. But anyway thanks for the reply.